# Tagging friends in photo android

Tags: android, facebook, photo, tagging

I was searching around to find answer to my question but I couldn't.

Can anyone tell me or at least guide me that How can I **Tag** friends to photo which I am gonna upload(post) to Facebook. Searching around I know that this is possible but I can't find the way how can I do it.

Can anyone guide me?
I have seen in many apps this option of *tagging friends* so I know this is possible and someone knows the answer to that. Please share with me. I will be thankful to *him/her*.

Answer (score 1):

See the photo API reference here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/#tags

From the docs, you can do it a few different ways, I'm showing you a couple below. Assuming that you have the PHOTO_ID of the photo you want to tag, the first method tags a single user, and gives an (x,y) of where their face is. Note that the (x,y) are not exact coordinates in the photo, but are instead percentage points.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("to", "USER_ID");
params.putInt("x", 25);
params.putInt("y", 25);
Request tagRequest = new Request(session, "PHOTO_ID/tags", params, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        // Do something here
    }
});
tagRequest.executeAsync();
```

Or you can tag many people at once like this (you can also construct a JSON object, and then pass the toString to the "tags" parameter).

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("tags", "[{\"tag_uid\": \"USER_ID_1\"},{\"tag_uid\": \"USER_ID_2\"}]");
Request tagRequest = new Request(session, "PHOTO_ID/tags", params, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        // Do something here
    }
});
tagRequest.executeAsync();
```

Note that I did not test the above code, so you should only use this as a guide.

Comment: I have seen that, but I dont know where to start. I have implemented facebook login successfully using [http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/) . Can you provide some code snippets ?

Comment: What if I want to tag the photo, before upload? Because in this case I won't have the PHOTO_ID. right? So, In that case how would I do that? Thanks for you help

Comment: You can't, you need to upload the photo first so you can get the id. It doesn't make sense to tag a photo before it exists on Facebook.